# Is there a way to display ISO and shutter speed in live view on a Nikon D5300?

Tags: shutter, live-view, nikon-d5300

I just bought a Nikon D5300.

Is there a way to preview the frame with its ISO and shutter speed (in live view) before taking the picture?

Comment: Seeing as it takes a fraction of a second why not just take the shot?

Comment: Hi..this is my first camera... ever.. the option of seen a preview can help me understand better what does shutter speed and Iso can do to my picture. So...in D5300 I dont have that option?

Comment: I don't think so. But in any case... take a shot... adjust the settings... take another shot... flick back and forth between the two to see the difference.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What specific use case are you considering that makes you think you need this capability?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I preview the look of my frame before taking the shot, on the LCD of my D5100 after altering the settings?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33689/how-do-i-preview-the-look-of-my-frame-before-taking-the-shot-on-the-lcd-of-my-d)

Answer (score 1):

The D5300 can not change the aperture diaphragm on the vast majority of Nikon lenses while the mirror is up. This is because the same mechanism that moves the mirror also provides the mechanical movement to stop down the aperture. Thus, to change the aperture setting when the mirror is up, such as with Live View, the mirror must drop down and back up for the mechanical aperture linkage to stop down the aperture in the lens. This is pretty much the case with all of Nikon's consumer grade DSLRs (D3x00 and D5x00 series).

If you bought the D5300 very recently with the new AF-P 18-55mm lens introduced in 2016 you *might* be able to do this in the future *if* Nikon updates the D5300's firmware to take advantage of the electronic aperture control of the AF-P lens. But as far as I can tell without actually testing that camera/lens combo, it doesn't seem that Nikon has made a provision in the D5300's current firmware to exploit the possibility. If they have I could find no reference to such in online reviews and comments. The original 18-55mm kit lens for the D5300 was the AF-S DX 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G ED VR II. That is still the lens being offered with the D5300 at major online retailers that still have inventories of D5300 kits. (The current model is the D5600 introduced in mid-2016 which followed the D5500 that supplanted the D5300 in early 2015.)

For more concerning the difference between lenses with mechanically controlled apertures and lenses with electronically controlled apertures as well as what "E" lenses are available in Nikon's lens lineup, please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/81904/15871) to another question. There is also at least one Nikon mount third party lens offered with electronic aperture control: [What are the advantages of Tamron SP 85mm f/1.8 over the Nikon 85mm f/1.8G?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82049/what-are-the-advantages-of-tamron-sp-85mm-f-1-8-over-the-nikon-85mm-f-1-8g/82075#82075)

At least one other maker uses an electronic aperture control on all of their lenses that allows the camera to control the aperture in the lens via a data link to a servo located inside the lens, rather than a mechanical connection from the camera body. Nikon has started making a few lenses with electronic aperture control, but for now they are mainly their more expensive lenses. All Canon EF lenses made since 1987 have electronic aperture control.

Comment: would you choose a canon eos 700 rather than a nikon d5300?

Comment: I would, but then I already own several Canon lenses. If I were starting out fresh it would all depend upon for exactly what I wished to use it.

Comment: FWIW, the kit lens which comes with the D5300 is the 18-55mm AF-P (i.e. electronic aperture).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Which is one out of pretty much *all* of the consumer grade Nikon lenses. The vast majority of electronic aperture lenses in Nikon's current lineup are super telephotos or other very expensive ($3K+) lenses. There are a handful of  moderately expensive ($1K-3K) Nikon lenses with e-aperture control, but most of Nikon's lenses in that range are not. So that option would only be available with the single kit lens and probably not any other lenses an owner with only a single D5300 would consider affordable.

Comment: @PeterTaylor When the D5300 was introduced the AF-P 18-55mm hadn't yet been released. As introduced the 18-55mm kit lens for the D5300 was the AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR II. Most D5300 kits had the AF-S DX 18-140mm f/3.5-5.6G ED VR instead of the 18-55.

Comment: The D5300 was introduced in late 2013. The AF-P 18-55mm wasn't introduced until mid 2016 with the D3400 and D5600. The 18-55mm kit lens for the D5500 was also the AF-S VR II version.

Comment: The AF-P 18-55mm is not even compatible with the original firmware of the D3300, D5300, or D5500 nor *any* pre-2013 Nikon DSLR.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Nikon has yet to implement an *Exposure-Priority* preview. It's really too bad as this is a good potential advantage when it comes to having a digital preview such as Live-View.

Keep in mind that no camera can perfectly preview exposure on all conditions. Particularly, anytime the flash is involved, the preview cannot predict how the flash will illuminate a scene. Also, very slow shutter-speeds are hard to preview. Many Panasonic cameras allow this but the preview becomes unusable since there is such a huge lag between image refreshes which is why it it Off by default.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the D5300 has a true DOF live preview - my D5500 doesn't.
It will also light-balance the screen so you can see it, whatever your exposure is going to be.

Just take the shot & look at it on the screen, tweak, repeat until happy.

If you don't have time to do that, then you didn't have time to check the Live Preview first anyway.

Answer (score -2):

In the live mode it's already being displaying the current shutter speed and the iso. please carefully check it.

Comment: hi... when I modify the iso or the shutter speed, the image in the lcd screen stays the same. Is it possible that the D5300 can not show a preview picture?